# how to create n DataFrame from a DataFrame of n columns?

Tags: pandas

Suppose you have a dataframe of n columns and want to create n dataframe. Each new DataFrame will contain all the values ​​of a column **and will be called as the column.**

> Example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['cities','games','jobs'])
df['cities']='Londres Paris'.split()
df['games']='Fornite mw2'.split()
df['jobs']='engineers programmers'.split()
df
```

Output:

```
    cities  games   jobs
0   Londres Fornite engineers
1   Paris   mw2     programmers
```

An efficient and extrapolable way for dataframes with a large number of columns is sought whose name is unknown.
Therefore you must deduct the name of each new dataframe from the names of each column.

**Required Departures:**

```
cities
```

Out:

```
    cities
0   Londres
1   Paris
```

---

```
games
```

Out:

```
    games
0   Fornite
1   mw2
```

---

```
jobs
```

Output:

```
    jobs
0   engineers
1   programmers
```

I want to create new `DataFrame` **whose names or reference are the str contained in `df.columns`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to create a dictionary, where the keys are the dataframes/column names and the values are actual dataframes:

```
dfs = {f'{col}':df[col].to_frame() for col in df.columns}
```

Now we can access each dataframe:

```
          jobs
0    engineers
1  programmers

dfs['games']
     games
0  Fornite
1      mw2

df['jobs']
          jobs
0    engineers
1  programmers
```

Comment: isn't it same as just calling `df['cities']` etc

Comment: the problem is that you need to be able to access the object only by running `jobs` or `game` etc...without this it would be a trivial problem

Comment: why would you want that perse, storing it in a dictionary makes more sense @lostCode